# vector subscript out of range error message

Tags: c++

I was trying one of the project euler problems, the first one where it asked you to calculate the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000. 
I attempted it and it shows no errors, however when i run it i get a message box with the error:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...\c++ learning\project euler ex 1\Debug\project euler ex 1.exe
File: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector
Line: 932

Expression: vector subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

Abort   Retry   Ignore
```

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using std::endl; using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
vector<int> five;
vector<int> three;
int x;
int y;
int sum;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 5)
{
    five.push_back(i);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 3)
{
    three.push_back(i);
}



for(vector<int>::iterator it = five.begin(); it != five.end(); ++it)
{
    if (five[*it] % 3 == 0)
    {
        it = five.erase(it);
    }
}

for(vector<int>::iterator it = three.begin(); it != three.end(); ++it)
{
    if (three[*it] % 5 == 0)
    {
        it = three.erase(it);
    }
}

x = accumulate(five.begin(), five.end(), 0);
cout << x << endl;

y = accumulate(three.begin(), three.end(), 0);
cout << y << endl;

sum = x + y;
cout << sum << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I know there is a much easier way to do that problem, however i am still learning c++ and wanted to try and use some of the things i had recently learnt.

Comment: Start looping from end of vectors, not from begin.

Comment: Never modify a collection you iterating over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::vector<T>::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) will return you an iterator following the last removed element. If you remove the last element, the returned iterator will be `end()`. And then you increment the iterator and get an exception. Also, even if you don't delete the last entry but another, you will still ignore the following element.

By the way, what do you want to achieve with `five[*it]`? The iterator acts like a pointer to a given element in the container. Either use a simple for-loop with an `int i`  and `five[i]` (which will have the same problems I stated above) *or* `*it`.<sup>*</sup>

Try the following code instead:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = five.begin(); it != five.end();)
{
    if (*it % 3 == 0)
    {
        it = five.erase(it);
    }
    else
         ++it;
}
```

<sub>* While it's true that the value of your iterator is its own key this will only last until you first changed the vector. So after your very first erase `five[*it] != *it`.</sub>

Comment: Just noticed that you are a C++-beginner. An iterator will act as an intelligent pointer. You can almost dereference all iterators and increment them, independent of the actual memory (continous or not) they are pointing too. Also note that `push_back` is a very expensive method. Try to allocate the vector first by using either resize or the `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t)` constructor. Also, if you want to delete and add many elements, a `dequeue` or `list` would suit you better. Notice that you won't need to change much other things, as they all provide iterators.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is done by the two first `for` loops. The first loop will gather all integers multiple of 3 and the second one all the integers multiple of five. The loops performing erasures are redundant (and in these loops lies your problem using `erase` on iterator already used in the loops)